# Is "short fall" an acceptable synonym for "shortfall"?

Tags: orthography

Is "short fall" an acceptable synonym for "shortfall"?

> We noticed an important short fall here that no-one else had planned for.

Found on an English-language Korean news [website](http://www.arirang.co.kr/News/News_View.asp?nseq=136204&code=Ne8&category=1).

I search in my dictionary but it did not have a "short fall" entry. Maybe that is an acceptable word nonetheless?

Comment: -1 research effort missing. Voting to close Too Localized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The noun is [*shortfall*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/shortfall).

Its derivation is from "fall short," not "short fall."